# Apache DS LDAP Server Fails to Start After Schema Addition

Tags: apache-http-server, ldap, apacheds

In an attempt to add the `memberOf` and `sAMAccountName` attributes from MSFT, I'm importing the LDIF found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34502363/7355697). The import succeeds and the new attributes appear in the tree but when I restart the server it fails to launch. There are no errors in "%userprofile%\.ApacheDirectoryStudio\.metadata\.log".

In fact, I can reproduce this by adding only the first part of the LDIF:

```
dn: cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: metaSchema
objectclass: top
cn: microsoft
```

[image: GIF of what happens]

I'm starting from a brand new server instance. Any ideas?

Win 10 x64

Apache Directory Studio Version: 2.0.0.v20180908-M14

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Which Java version are you using? I had a similar issue and got fixed by moving to Java 11.